# command "pm2 reload all" can't restart

Tags: reload, pm2

**1.I use command**

```
pm2 start pm2.json
```

**my pm2.json is**

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "name": "test_pm2",
    "script": "www/app.js",
    "cwd": "/var/www/test_pm2",
    "exec_mode": "cluster",
    "instances": 0,
    "max_memory_restart": "1G",
    "autorestart": true,
    "node_args": [],
    "args": [],
    "env": {

    }
  }]
}
```

**2.then i use command**

```
pm2 reload all
```

and pm2 stop all process,but can't relaod my project,The command line is always waiting.
To visit my project throgh browser,the Nginx 502 error showed.
So i have to use commond `pm2 start pm2.json` to start.

My environment:
pm2 v2.4.0; node v6.9.5; npm v3.10.10

I hope someone can answer the confusion, thanks！

Answer (score 0):

Just looking over your file these *may* be the problems. (not sure)

```
"apps": [{
"name": "test_pm2",
"script": "www/app.js",
"cwd": "/var/www/test_pm2",
"exec_mode": "cluster",
"instances": 0,
"max_memory_restart": "1G",
"autorestart": true,
"node_args": [],
"args": [],
"env": {

}
```

script: --> are you sure this is the correct path?? Usually it would read:
`"./app.js",`

cwd: ---> maybe it is `var\html\www` ???
If all else fails try `instances: 'max'`
and get rid of the `max_memory_restart`

Also make sure you are running the app.js by way of the pm2.json file (kind of obvious).

To see where the problem is coming from do it step by step. Some of the commands in your pm2.json file may be problematic.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

answering my own question ！

The pm2.log is:

```
    ===============================================================================
2017-03-31 13:23:12: --- PM2 global error caught ---------------------------------------------------
2017-03-31 13:23:12: Time                 : Fri Mar 31 2017 13:23:12 GMT+0800 (CST)
2017-03-31 13:23:12: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
2017-03-31 13:23:12: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
    at ChildProcess.onClose (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/TreeKill.js:104:26)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
2017-03-31 13:23:12: ===============================================================================
2017-03-31 13:23:12: [PM2][%s] Resurrecting PM2
2017-03-31 13:23:12: Stopping app:tadx_sys id:_old_1
/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/TreeKill.js:104
    allData.match(/\d+/g).forEach(function (pid) {
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
    at ChildProcess.onClose (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/TreeKill.js:104:26)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/tadx.borui-ad.com/undefined'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

I have found a solution for the issue in PM2 official GitHub page [Go to issue url](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2715)

> Upgrade to PM2 greater than v2.4.0